# Error filtering template: Invalid attribute name

Tags: php, installation, magento2

I have installed Magento 2.1.8 and installed sconto theme. Frontend showed some error like

> Error filtering template: Invalid attribute name.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, please go to admin and create an product attribute with attribute code is featured and assign this attribute to attribute set.
Or you can remove the featured product block from 'Home page for sconto' cms page in admin.